# 2,4 dihydroxy benzoate formation

Tags: organic-chemistry

When resorcinol and potassium hydrogen carbonate are added to each other in acidic conditions together with water, 2,4-dihydroxybenzoate is formed.

What kind of reaction is this? and what is a possible mechanism for it?

Comment: Are you sure about the acidic conditions? That will destroy the hydrogen carbonate. Now in basic conditions it can work.

Comment: HCl is also used so I assumed it is simply for acidifying

Comment: HCl would be used at the end of the reaction to form the acid from the potassium salt for precipitation or extraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This reaction has been studied in basic conditions by Barbarossa et al. [[1](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcou.2015.04.004)] using $\ce{KOH}$, $\ce{KHCO3}$ and $\ce{K2CO3}$ under $\ce{CO2}$.

Two mechanisms are offered in the paper, the first one looks to be more relevant for the example the OP quoted.

> [image]

#### References

1. Barbarossa, V.; Barzagli, F.; Mani, F.; Lai, S.; Vanga, G. The Chemistry of Resorcinol Carboxylation and Its Possible Application to the CO₂ Removal from Exhaust Gases. *Journal of CO₂ Utilization* **2015**, 10, 50–59. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcou.2015.04.004.